# MySql Keeping reusing Result of an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So two questions really:

```
SELECT CurrencyRateID, Rate, Markup
FROM currency_rate 
WHERE CurrencyID = (SELECT CurrencyID FROM currency WHERE BaseCurr = 1) **A** AND
DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) 
            FROM currency_rate 
            WHERE CurrencyID = **B**)
```

1. Why does this query give me an
   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'CurrercyID' in 'field list'
2. How can I use the result of the first SELECT Statement A in B

Comment: Does table `currency_rate` has `CurrencyID` column?

Comment: Did you copy/paste that error message? If so, you have misspelled the column somewhere since the error calls it `CurrercyID`. Note the 'r' where 'n' should be

Comment: @Jonny : use table aliases and then before each CurrencyID specify alias to explicitly define fromw hich table

Comment: yes I didn't notice it but the thing is that I copied the query which appears to be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully your `currency_rate` table has a unique identifier column.

If it does, you can merge queries A and B into a single query in the WHERE clause...

```
SELECT
  CurrencyRateID, Rate, Markup
FROM
  currency_rate 
WHERE
  uniqueID = (
              SELECT uniqueID
              FROM   currency_rate
              WHERE  CurrencyID = (SELECT CurrencyID FROM currency WHERE BaseCurr = 1)
              ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1
             )
```

If not, you may just have to repeat yourself...

```
SELECT CurrencyRateID, Rate, Markup
FROM currency_rate 
WHERE CurrencyID = (SELECT CurrencyID FROM currency WHERE BaseCurr = 1)
AND DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) 
            FROM currency_rate 
            WHERE CurrencyID = (SELECT CurrencyID FROM currency WHERE BaseCurr = 1))
```

Note: Even though the code repeats itself, it's likely that MySQL will notice the repeition and only perform the query once.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that you could simplify the first option to just use the sub-query...

```
  SELECT CurrencyRateID, Rate, Markup
  FROM   currency_rate
  WHERE  CurrencyID = (SELECT CurrencyID FROM currency WHERE BaseCurr = 1)
  ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if currencyID column exists in currency table and change query this way, so you can use statement A in where clause.

```
SELECT CurrencyRateID, Rate, Markup
FROM currency_rate cr inner join 
   (SELECT CurrencyID FROM currency WHERE BaseCurr = 1) **A**
   ON cr.CurrencyID = a.CurrencyID 
WHERE cr.DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) 
            FROM currency_rate 
            WHERE CurrencyID = A.CurrencyID)
```